# A lot of ambiguity errors using C++ Builder 10 Seattle

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I have gotten a lot of **ambiguity** errors when compiling older code in the new C++ Builder 10 Seattle. For functions like **log()** for example.

Calling **log(10)** generates the following error.

> [bcc32 Error] E2015 Ambiguity between 'std::log(float) at c:\program
>   files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:394'
>   and 'std::log(long double) at c:\program files
>   (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:430'

Feels like it should be able to handle that conversion. A warning, fine... but an error and unable to compile? Has the compiler gotten way more strict about this with later versions? Code is originally from **C++ Builder 2010**.

Other ambiguity errors include **void*** when **HWND** was expected, doing things like arithmetic on **TDateTimePicker->Time** (*->Time.Val* must be used now instead) etc. This was swallowed by the compiler before but not now. I'm happy it seems to be stricter now though... But it brings with it a lot of fixes to the old code.

Comment: But the integer `10` could be implicitly converted to *any* floating point type, so which one should the compiler choose? Instead of picking one (and risking picking the wrong) the compiler will fail instead. This is of course allowed (or maybe even required?) by the C++ standard.

Comment: I understand that. But since it worked before (and has also worked in versions of Visual C++) it's a bit strange. The compiler could have checked the number and converted it to a float or double depending on the number. Also, couldn't 10.0 be both a floating point number to? But I'm all for stricter compilers... I was just wondering if I had missed anything. But the old C++ Builder 2010 was way to loose and have resulted in a lot of strange code I now have to clean up. Like temporary objects/structs as default arguments in functions etc :P

Comment: int: 10, float: 10.0f, double: 10.0

Comment: Well, this is using the "classic" bcc32 compiler. So they seem to have made that a bit more strict to. I have HATED working with C++ Builder 2010 being used to other offerings. But with the newest version they have started to get a lot of things right. Still some way to go, but MUCH better.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you gave it an integer and it doesn't know what the resulting floating-point type should be.  If you said `log(10.0)` the type defaults to `double` and it has no ambiguity. Just because the original integer had no suffix doesn't mean the compiler can assume you want a no-suffix version of the converted floating-point value. C++ gets a lot more picky about strong typing as the versions wear on, so this sort of insistence popping up in newer compilers isn't surprising.

NB: Just adding a suffix won't work. `10f` doesn't mean it's a `float`. You need the decimal or the exponent (or both), also, so `10.f` works and `1e1f` works and `1.e1f` works as well.